# Laravel search many to many eloquent get result by pagination

Tags: search, eloquent, pagination

I have tree table:

1. posts
2. categories
3. tags

the posts fields are : title and text
the categories field is : title
the tags field is : title

the relation between posts and categories is many to many.
the relation between posts and tags is many to many.

I want search keyword in title or body of posts (like), or in title of post categories, or title of post tags using eloquent and pagination.

How do I do this?

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
    }
}

class Tag extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the best query :

```
$posts = Post::where('title','LIKE','%'.$keyword.'%')
        ->orWhereHas('tags', function($query) use ($keyword) {
            $query->where('title', $keyword);
        })
        ->orWhereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($keyword) {
            $query->where('title', $keyword);
        })->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(10)->appends('keyword', $keyword);
```